# CNContactPickerViewController when contact has multiple mails

Tags: swift, cncontactpicker

I'm using a CNContactPickerViewController to let the user select the email of one of his/her contacts

```
let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
contactPicker.delegate = self
contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate(format: "emailAddresses.@count > 0")
contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactNicknameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey]
```

When the contact has only one mail, everything goes well

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {

    if let _mail = contact.emailAddresses.first?.value as String? {
        self.personWasSelected(with: _mail)
    }
}
```

But sometimes one of the contacts has more than one mail, how can I let the user select on one of those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found the solution by trial-error...

I was implementing both:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
    if let _mail = contactProperty.value as? String {
        self.personWasSelected(with: _mail)
    }
}

func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {

    if let _mail = contact.emailAddresses.first?.value as String? {
        self.personWasSelected(with: _mail)
    }
}
```

But only the first one should have been implemented

Answer (score 4):

To let a user choose which email address to select, set

```
picker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "emailAddresses.@count > 0")
picker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate(format: "emailAddresses.@count == 1")
```

This way, for users with only one email

```
contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact)
```

gets called, but for users with more than one email, the contact detail is presented and the selected email is passed to

```
contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty)
```

Note that `CNContactProperty` also has the `.contact` attribute.